Update Python code to do Text to Columns action with Azure Function App
I'm using an Azure Function App with Python that converts csv to xlsx. This works fine however, the StartDate and LeaveDate column data appears on the left side of the columns which tells me its not correct. I need to then do a Text to columns action on the columns which gives me the output I need. Can anyone look at my code and make some suggestions please to achieve this? Thanks Ross
import azure.functions as func
import logging
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import os
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
import io
from io import BytesIO 
import numpy as np

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    connect_str = os.environ["AzureWebJobsStorage"]
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
    container_name_input = "input"
    container_name_output = "output"
   
    # Get container and blob name from request parameters (or modify for local testing)
    container_name = req.params.get('container')
    blob_name = req.params.get('name')

    blob_client_input = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=blob_name)
    blob_content = blob_client_input.download_blob().readall()

    # Use BytesIO to wrap downloaded bytes
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(blob_content))
    except UnicodeDecodeError:  # Handle potential encoding issues (optional)
        # If you suspect encoding issues, try different encodings here
        df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(blob_content), encoding='utf-16')  # Example for UTF-16

  # Convert StartDate column to datetime format with the correct format string
    df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
    df['LeaveDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['LeaveDate'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

    # Format StartDate column to dd/mm/yyyy
    df['StartDate'] = df['StartDate'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    df['LeaveDate'] = df['LeaveDate'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

    output = BytesIO()
    # Create an instance of xlsxwriter.Workbook
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output, {'remove_timezone': True})  # Add options to remove timezone warning
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet1')
    
    # Write column headers to the worksheet
    for col_num, col_name in enumerate(df.columns):
        worksheet.write(0, col_num, col_name)

    # Write DataFrame rows to the worksheet starting from row 1 (excluding headers)
    for row_num, row_data in enumerate(df.values, start=1):
        for col_num, value in enumerate(row_data):
            worksheet.write(row_num, col_num, value)

    # Add a date format for the StartDate and LeaveDate columns.
    date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd/mm/yyyy'})
    worksheet.set_column('H:I', None, date_format)

    # Use close() to finalize the Excel workbook
    workbook.close()

    # Create output blob with correct extension
    output_blob_name = blob_name.replace('.csv', '.xlsx')
    excel_blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name_output, blob=output_blob_name)
    excel_blob_client.upload_blob(output.getvalue())

    # Delete the input CSV file
    blob_client_input.delete_blob()

    return func.HttpResponse(f"CSV file converted to XLSX: {output_blob_name}. Input CSV file deleted.")


Same as doing a text to columns action in excel


Below code worked for me.
import azure.functions as func
import logging
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import os
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
import io
from io import BytesIO

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    connect_str = os.environ["StorageAccountConnectionString"]
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
    container_name_output = "samples-workitems"
   
    # Get container and blob name from request parameters (or modify for local testing)
    container_name = req.params.get('container')
    blob_name = req.params.get('blob')

    blob_client_input = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=blob_name)
    blob_content = blob_client_input.download_blob().readall()

    # Use BytesIO to wrap downloaded bytes
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(blob_content))
    except UnicodeDecodeError:  # Handle potential encoding issues (optional)
        # If you suspect encoding issues, try different encodings here
        df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(blob_content), encoding='utf-16')  # Example for UTF-16

    # Convert StartDate column to datetime format with the correct format string
    df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
    df['LeaveDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['LeaveDate'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

    # Format StartDate column to dd/mm/yyyy
    df['StartDate'] = df['StartDate'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    df['LeaveDate'] = df['LeaveDate'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    
    # Replace NaN values with a placeholder (e.g., "N/A")
    df.fillna("N/A", inplace=True)

    output = BytesIO()
    # Create an instance of xlsxwriter.Workbook
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output, {'remove_timezone': True})  
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet1')
    
    # Write column headers to the worksheet
    for col_num, col_name in enumerate(df.columns):
        worksheet.write(0, col_num, col_name)

    # Write DataFrame rows to the worksheet starting from row 1 (excluding headers)
    for row_num, row_data in enumerate(df.values, start=1):
        for col_num, value in enumerate(row_data):
            # Check if the value is NaN
            if pd.isna(value):
                value = "N/A"  # Replace NaN with placeholder
            worksheet.write(row_num, col_num, value)

    # Add a date format for the StartDate and LeaveDate columns.
    date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd/mm/yyyy'})
    worksheet.set_column('A:B', None, date_format)

    # Use close() to finalize the Excel workbook
    workbook.close()

    # Create output blob with correct extension
    output_blob_name = blob_name.replace('.csv', '.xlsx')
    excel_blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name_output, blob=output_blob_name)
    excel_blob_client.upload_blob(output.getvalue())

    # Delete the input CSV file
    blob_client_input.delete_blob()

    return func.HttpResponse(f"CSV file converted to XLSX: {output_blob_name}. Input CSV file deleted.")

requirements.txt-
azure-functions
azure-storage-blob
pandas
XlsxWriter

I am able to get the expected response by executing the given code.



If any column in your sheet contains blank value then it will get updated to N/A.


Hi thanks. I forgot to mention  that under the LeaveDate column there will be blank cells, will this still work? Thanks @Ikhtesam Afrin

@RossSutherland please try my code once if it doesn't work you can share the error message too

I got this error: [2024-04-26T09:15:38.512Z] Executed 'Functions.http_trigger' (Failed, Id=ac9f20da-7c4b-4f55-a9da-f54e9232422e, Duration=1105ms)
[2024-04-26T09:15:38.515Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.http_trigger. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: TypeError: NAN/INF not supported in write_number() without 'nan_inf_to_errors' Workbook() option

@RossSutherland Are you getting any error?

Sorry comment sent before I could paste error - see above. Thanks

Are you using my code or have you made any changes to it

Updated above. only bit I changed was to ensure connections were correct. Updated from encoding='utf-16') down

@RossSutherland Also share the screenshot of your csv file

added above, as a link - sorry, don't use stackover flow as much as a I should :) @Ikhtesam Afrin

@RossSutherland LeaveDate column is blank?

Yeah, this is what I was saying earlier and forgot to mention in my original post. This is an employee file so will always have a startdate but will occasionally have an end date when someone is due to leave.

@RossSutherland got it, I will try this case and will get back to you soon

Ok, ran through,  got NA in the LeaveDate column, but the StartDate cells the dates sit to the left, so had to text to columns action in excel to get the output I need so doesn't solve that issue. Its a funny one as when taking the CSV file and just doing save as xlsx it keeps the date formatting but using python to convert its loses the formatting

@RossSutherland In my case, the result comes like this after downloading the blob.

ok, no worries, appreciate the help. Thanks again.

@RossSutherland which alignment you want?

Its not about allignment as when you do text to columns it moves the dates to right of the column anyway. This link kind of explains it - https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/1babiyk/replicating_excel_text_to_columns_in_python/

@RossSutherland got it
